# Questions relating the definition of conditional expectation $E[g(X)|M]$ where is $X$ is random variable and M is an event

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I saw the following definition of conditional expectation from a book:

> if M is event and X is continuous random variable then we define:
>   $$E[X|M]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x|M)dx$$

Which is the regular definition where $f(x)$ is replaced by the conditional density $f(x|M)$.

Now I got also the theorem which says that:

> Let $X$ be random variable and $Y=g(X)$ (for some function) so the Y is also random variable, then:
>
> $$E[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_Y(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)dx$$

Which is well known theorem.

Now, my problem is when i tried to define:
$$E[g(X)|M]$$
where $X$ is random variable and M is an event.

Can I say that:
$$E[g(X)|M]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_{X|M}(x|M)dx$$
Or that I need to assume $Y=g(X)$ and then:

$$E[g(X)|M]=E[Y|M]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_{Y|M}(y|M)dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_{Y|M}(g(x)|M)d(g(x))$$

Or that is even something else?
**Can you please explain how $f_{Y|M}$ is defined**

maybe I didn't understand the second "theorem"
The source for the second "theorem" (from PROBABILITY, RANDOM VARIABLES, AND STOCHASTIC PROCESSES, Athanasios Papoulis):
[image]

Comment: Your second "theorem" implies that $\int yf(y)dy=\int g(y)f(y)dy$ for any function $g$. Does this seem plausible to you?

Comment: @MikeHawk
I will tell you the truth, I think it does not, but when reading it in the book I didn't find any limitation on $g$.
I added the source.

Comment: You cannot ignore the subscripts in "$f_x$" (equation 5-55) and "$f_y$" (equation 5-54).

Comment: @whuber I thought it was understood, but I edited it. 
can you please answer I define E[g(X)|M]?

Comment: When "$f$" appears on both sides of an equation but is intended to mean two different things, you are asking for confusion.  I suspect that's at the root of what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @whuber, I agree with you. I tried to edit the post again. can you please see it again, and try to answer my question?

Comment: I don't think I need to add anything to what has already been written extensively on this site: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+expectation+definition+score%3A2.